# Google Admin Api- User provisioning to Organisational Unit Give Error: 403

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-admin-settings-api

Hi All Geniuses buddies

I am using google admin apis. user provisioning is what i successfully performed.
When i try to move the same user to Organisational Unit(OU). It give me error like

{"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."}
You are not authorised to access this api.

I am not able to figure out which api i need to trun on for that.
Here are the api i have truned on.[image]

This it the code i am using to perform the same

```
            //Method 1
 OrganizationService serviceNew = new OrganizationService("Domain", "User Provisioning");

 serviceNew.setUserCredentials("Admin Email Account", "Password");


 serviceNew.UpdateOrganizationUser("Customer ID", "The Email Account i want to add", "/OU Name", "/");
```

I dont know why its not working.

!Any help, It will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the user have administration permissions? have you granted the app to access that kind of information in the admin console?

Comment: Thanks gerardo. All the apis mentioned above are truned on. where do i need to grant access else?

Answer (score 0):

You have to grant the application access to your domain.
In the Admin Console of your domain go to (admin.google.com):
Security >  Advanced Settings > In the Authentication section go to "Manage API client access"

There you have to add the client name, which is the client id of the app (looks like a long email) and in the field "One or More API Scopes" you have to add the all scopes that your app is using separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes to my code. Instead of moving user to Organisation Unit,I just updated it to the Organisation Unit path.
And See What it worked like charm. :)
Thanks Gerardo, for showing interest. Keep the good work going.